# Biblatex - Shortauthor length problem

Tags: biblatex

I cite the Android Open Source Project multiple times in my work. So i just declare the same shortauthor multiple times like this:

```
@ONLINE{online_android_apiguides_services,
    TITLE        = {Android API Guides - Services},
    AUTHOR       = {{Android Open Source Project}},
    SHORTAUTHOR  = {AOSP},
    URL          = {http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html},
    URLDATE      = {2015-03-12}
 }
@ONLINE{online_android_reference_service,
    TITLE        = {Android Reference - Service},
    AUTHOR       = {{Android Open Source Project}},
    SHORTAUTHOR  = {AOSP},
    URL          = {http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html},
    URLDATE      = {2015-03-12}
 }
```

The desired output is "[AOSPa]" and "[AOSPb]". However the actual output is "[AOSa]" and "[AOSb]".

In general I want the 3 character form (like when it does this automatically for lastnames), but when I explicitly declare a shortauthor, I don't want this shortened.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I declare the bibliography this way:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex8,
        style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\bibliography{mybib}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Without seeing how exactly you process the bibliography (at least which style you use), it's difficult to give an answer. Anyways, have you tried `SHORTAUTHOR={{AOSP}}` ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that, and didn't work for me.

I use the style alphabetic. I edited the original post.

Comment: Instead of ShortAuthor, using ShortHand seems to work. However, it does result in repeated labels (ASOP instead of ASOPa ASOPb) for multiple citations

Comment: @MobiusPizza Interestingly, with Biber your approach works as well, just not with BibTeX. The `label` field works well with all back-ends, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `label` field. The `biblatex` doc says that `label` is "[a] designation to be used by the citation style as a substitute for the regular label if any data required to generate the regular label is missing" (p. 20 of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)).
Fortunately, with the `alphabetic` style the `label` is given precedence over the `labelname`, it is also used in its entirety.

Hence

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,
        style=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@ONLINE{online_android_apiguides_services,
    TITLE        = {Android API Guides - Services},
    AUTHOR       = {{Android Open Source Project}},
    label  = {AOSP},
    URL          = {http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html},
    URLDATE      = {2015-03-12}
 }
@ONLINE{online_android_reference_service,
    TITLE        = {Android Reference - Service},
    AUTHOR       = {{Android Open Source Project}},
    label  = {AOSP},
    URL          = {http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html},
    URLDATE      = {2015-03-12}
 }
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

does exactly what you want.

If you use Biber, the approach with `shorthand` as suggested in the comments works as well; with BibTeX(8) you will get no disambiguation, though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
        style=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@ONLINE{online_android_apiguides_services,
    TITLE        = {Android API Guides - Services},
    AUTHOR       = {{Android Open Source Project}},
    shorthand  = {AOSP},
    URL          = {http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html},
    URLDATE      = {2015-03-12}
 }
@ONLINE{online_android_reference_service,
    TITLE        = {Android Reference - Service},
    AUTHOR       = {{Android Open Source Project}},
    shorthand  = {AOSP},
    URL          = {http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html},
    URLDATE      = {2015-03-12}
 }
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]